# How to prove that sequence spaces $l^{p}, l^{\infty}$ and function space $C[a. b]$ are of infinite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

I am studying about the sequence space $l^{p}, l^{\infty}$ and function space $C[a. b]$. It is mentioned in the book that all of these spaces are of infinite dimension. I want to prove that these spaces are of infinite dimension. I am not finding a way to proceed.

Any help and suggestions would be helpful to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to construct infinitely many linearly independent vectors. For $l_p$ and $l_{\infty}$ take vectors $(0,0,0,...0,1.....).$ For $C[a,b]$ polynomials $x^n$ will do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mean that we can construct $1, x, x^2, x^3....$ as basis for $C[a, b]$?

Comment: $1,x,x^2...$ form linearly independent sequence which is infinite. Indeed, if $\sum_{k=0}^n\lambda_kx^k=0$ on $[a,b]$ then the polynomial has to be equal to zero identically. Hence, $\lambda_k=0$ and our sequence is indeed linearly independent.

Answer (score 4):

You can exhibit an infinite linearly independent family:

- For $\ell^p$ or $\ell^{\infty}$, consider the sequences of the form $(0,\dots,0,1,0, \dots)$.
- For $C([a,b])$, consider the functions $t \mapsto e^{ct}$.

**Remark:** In fact, the second point shows that $C([a,b])$ has dimension $\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain your answer. I am just beginner for this course finding it hard to get things from hint.

Comment: The first example is easier, can you show that the family is linearly independent? It is a direct consequence from the definition of linearly independence.

Comment: @Serios  Oh I got your point. Sequences of the form suggested by you belongs to $l^{p}$ and $l^{\infty}$ and we can construct infinitely many linearly independent such vectors as the basis of them. Am i correct?

Comment: In fact every separable Banach space has algebraic dimension $\mathfrak{c}$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** You need to find infinite linearly independent familiy in each of these spaces. I suggest you to search them among functions with disjoint supports.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't studied support so for.

Comment: As I understand you do not know the definition of support. Here it is $$\operatorname{supp}(f)=\operatorname{closure}_\Omega(\{x\in \Omega:f(x)\neq 0\})$$

Comment: @ Thanks Norbert for the help .